# Как правильно собирать временные метрики?

Tags: c#, .net, архитектура

Вопрос связан с тем что это мой первый опыт сбора метрик.
Правильно ли я собираю информацию о времени выполнения запроса сервером, к примеру у меня есть такой код:

```
// Один из методов контроллера
public IActionResult SomeMethod()
{
    DateTime metricsStart = DateTime.Now;
    try
    {
        // что то делаю и возвращаю клиенту результат

        return Json( auctions );
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        logger.LogError( $"error! ip:{accessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()} Discription: {e}." );
        return Json( "error" );
    }
    finally
    {
        string timeDifference= ( DateTime.Now - metricsStart ).TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
        logger.LogInformation( $"Ok. ip:  {accessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()} Time: {timeDifference}" );
    }
}
```

Это нормально?

Comment: Используйте [StopWatch](https://habrahabr.ru/post/226279/)

Comment: Т.е. как только вам понадобятся метрика, вы будете вынуждены писать кучу кода. Чтобы этого избежать, можно на action или controller навесить декоратор, он же фильтр в asp.net, тогда вам будет достаточно добавить атрибут. Если нужны метрики не только для asp.net, то смотрите в сторону интерцепторов. И да, для замера времени лучше Stopwatch

Comment: Так и знал что существует человеческий способ! Спасибо за ответ, он исчерпывающий.

Comment: @PrimusSingularis так может ответом?

Comment: @tym32167 согласен

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov но вообще по вашему вопросу - я бы для начала, перед тем, как руками править контроллеры, поглядел бы, что предоставляет сервер или фреймворк. Например, если вы хостите сайт на IIS, то там вроде можно настроить логгирование запросов. Или если, например, вы пишете на .net core, то вы можете настроить логирование всех запросов [при конфигурации приложения](https://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/asp-net-core-middleware-to-measure-request-processing-time).

Comment: Если хотите действительно собирать метрики - подключите app insights или new relic

Comment: Если метрик много, и они разнообразные, я рекомендую так же использовать аспектно-ориентированный подход, например, [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/framework). Он после компиляции видоизменяет сборку, добавляя в начало и конец помеченных своими атрибутами методов код, который вы описываете в специальных методах этих атрибутов.

Это позволит вам отделить логику замера времени и логирования от основной и не писать при этом множество декораторов. Достаточно будет пометить нужным атрибутом интересующие методы.

И да, используйте StopWatch, как говорят выше.

Comment: @NikolayLebedev никакой PostSharp автору не нужен, так как в asp.net mvc уже есть встроенная поддержка подобного - оно называется фильтры - тоже аттрибуты, с помощью которых можно отследить вызовы действий контроллеров - именно они и предлагались во втором комментарии.

Comment: @PashaPash и то и другое же вроде платное, ещё и софт надо какой то ставить на сервер, верно?

Comment: @tym32167  и там и там есть бесплатный план. App insights умеет собирать большую часть метрик без софта (подключается как фильтр в asp.net).  Это в любом случае дешевле и надежнее,  чем свой велосипед с ручным замером,  хранением и отображением метрик. Хотя да, не так интересно,  как убить месяц-второй на написание самописной *бесплатной* системы.

Comment: @PashaPash имхо не стоит так отметать самописный вариант. Все же зависит от требований. Вот я над своим сайтом тоже тружусь, и у меня будет примерно 20-40 пользователей, мне эти зависимости от внешних систем никуда не уперлись, проще 10 строк написать и мерить время нужных запросов. Потому бы не сказал, что самописное хуже, просто для каждого случая своё решение

Comment: @tym32167 ок, вы пытаетесь теоретически рассуждать, что вам так будет проще. Если вы уместите в 10 строк сбор метрик, их хранение и визуализацию - ок, вы гений и вам будет действительно проще делать что-то самописное. Но *вам* я ничего и не советую. Я советую *топикастеру* взять готовый инструмент, который подключается за 15 минут (из которых 14 - создание подписки в azure + минуту на подключение nuget пакета стандартным визардом студии).

Comment: @tym32167 вы посоветовали *топикастеру* самописный фильтр, с обоснованием. Я посоветовал *топикастеру* готовый условно-бесплатный сервис, с обоснованием. Совершенно не понимаю, что вы пытаетесь мне доказать. Я не буду использовать самописный вариант ни в одном из своих проектов, потому что мне дорого мое время. Но я не отказываю вам в праве тратить свою жизнь как угодно :)

Comment: @PashaPash я не советовал фильтр топикстартеру. Я просто прочитал ваше `Это в любом случае дешевле и надежнее, чем свой велосипед с ручным замером` и с этим не согласился, так как ситуации разные бывают. Ничего доказывать не собирался, я, как и вы, просто высказал свою точку зрения

Comment: Посоветую Zabbix. Сам пока нифига его не знаю, но мы будем его использовать для мониторинга наших сервисов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Правильный" подход к сбору метрик зависит от задачи.

Если хотите решить проблему вручную:

- Если вам нужно точечно отслеживать какие-то внутренние вызовы - возьмите PostSharp, и напишите свой `OnMethodBoundaryAspect`.
- Если хотите мерять только время выполнения MVC Action - напишите свой [`ActionFilterAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) и зарегистрируйте его как глобальный фильтр.

Используйте [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.7.1) вместо `DateTime`- иначе вам не хватит точности.

Если вам нужно просто собрать базовые метрики с сайта - подключите готовый production profiler: [App Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/) или [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/). Это даст вам метрики по времени выполнения запросов + метрики по SQL + метрики по клиентской стороне.

При желании, подходы можно комбинировать - кастомные метрики всегда можно дописать кодом и отправить в тот же AI.